# I have same size of Laptop and Tablet, but I want to hide a Button on Tablet not in Laptop..... How Can I do this?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In a Web Page I want a button should hide in tablet view but it should show in desktop OR laptop view..

I used media Query but what if size are same?

The Problem is I have same size of Laptop and Tablet now how can i do it.....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566168/what-is-the-perfect-way-to-detect-a-tablet Have a look here. Seems to be the same question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can use `height` & `width` like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (max-height:768px) {
   .your-class{display:none}
}
```

Or Your tablet is retina display you can write this way

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is with PHP. Look at the HTTP_USER_AGENT and if it is a tablet, you can not display the HTML.

Comment: A interviewer asked this question to my friend and said we can do this by css but how he did not tell....

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the operating system in javascript by using `window.ui.os`
and then call a javascript function to hide the button.

Answer (score 0):

> please use this media query I hope its working into your code...

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
    .btn {
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
    }
  } 
 
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .btn {
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px auto 5px 20px;
    width: 28%;
    display: none;
    }
    }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button1" class="btn" />
```